# QThreadPool example

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, threadpool

I'm looking for some concise example on the use of `QThreadPool`. Here's how I used it:

```
QThreadPool *thread_pool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();
MyThread *thread = new MyThread();
thread_pool->start(thread);


class MyThread : public QRunnable {
public:
    MyThread();
    ~MyThread();
    void run();
};

void MyThread::run()
{
    qDebug() << "MyThread";
}
```

Is the above the right practice ?
PS: I saw `waitForDone` in the reference, when should I call `waitForDone` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is almost correct with one exception. `QRunnable` is not a thread, and you should not call your class `MyThread`. `MyRunnable` or `MyTask` is more correct.

Note that your code is almost the same as the example on the [documentation page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#details). The documentation is the best source of concise examples.

You should call `waitForDone` when you want to wait until all runnables are processed. It depends on your app's architecture. Usually it's when you created and started all `QRunnable`s and want to use their results.

Comment: Does `waitforDone` actually remove "all the threads in the thread pool" or does it really empty all the `QRunnable` tasks in the task queue?